# Dateadd function doesnt completely showing all previous months value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, dateadd

I just want to ask about the issue I encountered I used this measurement

```
prev_total_cost = CALCULATE([m_total_cost], DATEADD(Date [REPORT_MONTH], -1, MONTH))
```

to fetch the previous month's value so that I can see the difference of my sales column. However, upon checking I noticed that for the month of June 2023 it doesn't show the value of May 2023 (please see attached image), supposedly it should show ($13497). Hope you can help me.

[image: 1]

Comment: "[m_total_cost]" is a measure?

Comment: yes its a measure

Comment: [m_total_cost] is column Total Cost

Comment: You can try using [PREVIOUSMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/previousmonth-function-dax) function, this should get you your desired value. ie: `prev_total_cost = CALCULATE([m_total_cost], PREVIOUSMONTH(Date [REPORT_MONTH]))`

Comment: same result nothing happened when I used previousmonth function

Comment: why don't you use the column instead of the measure? I always encounter this type of problems when I use measures.